# Cannot implement $('#sample-id').resizable()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've never really worked with jQuery before, I am only trying this out since this seems like an easier way to make the entire right border of a div element a resizing handle.

I want to use jQuery-resizable for the user to be able to resize #left-bar while browsing the page. I found an example snippet to work with that I have linked below.

First snippet is my original page, I am giving the entire CSS and HTML for you to be able to see what the page basically looks like, it'll be easier to understand that way I think.

The jQuery script is in the  section my html script.

I want this part to work the same way it does in the second snippet for my #left-bar:

```
jQuery('#one').resizable({
  direction: 'right'
})
```

**My page:**

```css
body {
  max-width: 1780px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 1830px;
  height: 100px;
}

#logo-container {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 220px;
  width: 366px;
  height: 30px;
}

#search-bar-container>input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: large;
}

#center-main {
  background-color: red;
  width: 1830px;
  height: 805px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  outline: thin solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.document {
  overflow: auto;
}

#left-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 255px;
  height: 805px;
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
  margin-right: 1px;
  /* resize: horizontal; ### */
  border: thin solid black;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-bar-icons {
  background-color: #b3b4b5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  outline: thin solid black;
}

#reset-container {
  background-color: #b3b4b5;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 195px;
}

#nav-bar-reset-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#reset-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toc {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 770px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.content {
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.content-drop {
  float: left;
}

.content-drop:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.l1-drop-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  ;
  display: none;
}

.l1-content-link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.l2-drop-container {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.l2-content-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.l1-content-drop:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#topic-window {
  background-color: #e9e9ed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* float:right; */
  outline: thin solid black;
  /* flex-grow: 5; ### */
}

#docWindow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.show-l2-content {
  display: block;
}

.show-left-bar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
  <title>Udex</title>
  <link href="style/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#left-bar").resizable({
        direction: 'right'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    <div id="logo-container">
      <a href="placeholder_page.html" target="docWindow">
        <img src="images/ulak.png" alt="ulak-logo" id="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="search-bar-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search documents...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main" id="center-main">
    <div class="nav-bar" id="left-bar">
      <div id="left-bar-icons">
        <div id="reset-container">
          <img src="images/reset.png" alt="reset-nav-bar" id="nav-bar-reset-icon">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="toc-container" id="toc">
        <div class="content">
          <img id="lib-info" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">Library Information</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <img id="feat-ovw" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png" onclick="dropDown('feat-ovw')">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">Feature Overview</a>
          <div class="l1-drop-container">
            <img class="l1-content-drop" id="feat-dtsht" src="images/plussearch.png" onclick="l1dropDown('feat-dtsht')">
            <a class="l1-content-link" href="feature_table_names.html" target="docWindow">Feature Datasheets</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <img id="feat-chg" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">Feature Changes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <img id="ran-fun" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">RAN Functions</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <img id="cld-air" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">CloudAIR</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <img id="net-inf" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
          <a class="content-link" href="#">Network Infrastructure</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="document" id="topic-window">
      <iframe id="docWindow" name="docWindow" src="placeholder_page.html"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="javascript/Search.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/dropDown.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/parent_dropDown.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/l1_dropDown.js"></script>


  <script id="table_anchors">
    var tableNames = ['NRDUCell', 'NRDUCellPucch', 'NRDUCellUlTaConfig', 'gNBRlcParamGroup', 'IntraFreqCellReselectionInfo', 'CellReselectionInfoCommon', 'gNBOperator', 'NRDUCellPrach', 'NRDUCellPusch', 'NRDUCellCsirs', 'NRDUCellPdsch', 'CellResServingFreqInfo', 'NRDUCellUlPcConfig', 'gNBDUDrxParamGroup', 'NRDUCellTrp', 'NRDUCellAlgoSwitch', 'NRDUCellUeTimerConst', 'NRDUCellSelConfig', 'NRDUCellDlSch', 'NRDUCellPdcch', 'NRCUCell', 'NRDUCellCoreset', 'gNodeBConf', 'NRDUCellIntrfParam', 'gNBTrackingArea', 'gNBSibConfig', 'NRDUCellCarrMgmt', 'NRDUCellSrs', 'NRDUCellPagingConfig', 'None', 'NRDUCellChnPwr', 'NRDUCellRimConfig', 'NRDUCellNsaDcConfig'];

    function createAnchorTags() {
      var l1DropContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.l1-drop-container');

      // Iterate through each table name
      for (var i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++) {
        var tableName = tableNames[i];

        const htmlScript = `<div class="l2-drop-container">
                    <a class="l2-content-link" href="feature_tables/${tableName}/homepage_${tableName}.html" target="docWindow">${tableName}</a>
                </div>`;

        var temporary_container = document.createElement('div');
        temporary_container.innerHTML = htmlScript;

        for (var j = 0; j < l1DropContainers.length; j++) {
          l1DropContainers[j].appendChild(temporary_container.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
        }
      }
    }
    createAnchorTags();
  </script>
</body>
```

**Link to the snippet I am taking as an example** [Working Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/uqv7cdjz/)

Comment: You also need to include the jQuery UI stylesheet. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: Also the one in the working snippet isn't using the jQuery UI's resizable plugin. It looks like its one made by someone else.

Comment: The snippet/fiddle uses: https://github.com/tannernetwork/resizable

Comment: vs jquery-ui resizable: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/  - if you don't use jquery-ui for anything else, then definitely look for an alternative (such as the tannernetwork one)

Comment: @imvain2 does including the stylesheet overlap with my own stylesheet or anything? Because that didn't do anything to my result.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am sorry but I really have no idea which one of those to include, or how to include them either. I've only been using jQuery for an estimate of... 3 hours.

Only just saw your edit, I'll make sure to check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">
```

note: in a real site you'll need to copy these to your site as rawgit.com will likely block them (you'll get errors in the console) - there may be a CDN but I only looked on cdnjs briefly.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#left-bar").resizable({
    direction: 'right'
  });
});


var tableNames = ['NRDUCell', 'NRDUCellPucch', 'NRDUCellUlTaConfig', 'gNBRlcParamGroup', 'IntraFreqCellReselectionInfo', 'CellReselectionInfoCommon', 'gNBOperator', 'NRDUCellPrach', 'NRDUCellPusch', 'NRDUCellCsirs', 'NRDUCellPdsch', 'CellResServingFreqInfo', 'NRDUCellUlPcConfig', 'gNBDUDrxParamGroup', 'NRDUCellTrp', 'NRDUCellAlgoSwitch', 'NRDUCellUeTimerConst', 'NRDUCellSelConfig', 'NRDUCellDlSch', 'NRDUCellPdcch', 'NRCUCell', 'NRDUCellCoreset', 'gNodeBConf', 'NRDUCellIntrfParam', 'gNBTrackingArea', 'gNBSibConfig', 'NRDUCellCarrMgmt', 'NRDUCellSrs', 'NRDUCellPagingConfig', 'None', 'NRDUCellChnPwr', 'NRDUCellRimConfig', 'NRDUCellNsaDcConfig'];

function createAnchorTags() {
  var l1DropContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.l1-drop-container');

  // Iterate through each table name
  for (var i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++) {
    var tableName = tableNames[i];

    const htmlScript = `<div class="l2-drop-container">
                    <a class="l2-content-link" href="feature_tables/${tableName}/homepage_${tableName}.html" target="docWindow">${tableName}</a>
                </div>`;

    var temporary_container = document.createElement('div');
    temporary_container.innerHTML = htmlScript;

    for (var j = 0; j < l1DropContainers.length; j++) {
      l1DropContainers[j].appendChild(temporary_container.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
}
createAnchorTags();
```

```css
/* main styling page, empty because there are no pages generated manually so we don't have to deal with this for now */

body {
  max-width: 1780px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 1830px;
  height: 100px;
}

#logo-container {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 220px;
  width: 366px;
  height: 30px;
}

#search-bar-container>input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: large;
}

#center-main {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  width: 1830px;
  height: 805px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  outline: thin solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.document {
  overflow: auto;
}

#left-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 255px;
  height: 805px;
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
  margin-right: 1px;
  /* resize: horizontal; ### */
  border: thin solid black;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-bar-icons {
  background-color: #b3b4b5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  outline: thin solid black;
}

#reset-container {
  background-color: #b3b4b5;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 195px;
}

#nav-bar-reset-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#reset-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toc {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 770px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.content {
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.content-drop {
  float: left;
}

.content-drop:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.l1-drop-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  ;
  display: none;
}

.l1-content-link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.l2-drop-container {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.l2-content-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.l1-content-drop:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#topic-window {
  background-color: #e9e9ed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* float:right; */
  outline: thin solid black;
  /* flex-grow: 5; ### */
}

#docWindow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.show-l2-content {
  display: block;
}

.show-left-bar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.js"></script> and add
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/tannernetwork/resizable/master/resizable.min.css">

<div id="top-bar">
  <div id="logo-container">
    <a href="placeholder_page.html" target="docWindow">
      <img src="images/ulak.png" alt="ulak-logo" id="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="search-bar-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search documents...">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main" id="center-main">
  <div class="nav-bar" id="left-bar">
    <div id="left-bar-icons">
      <div id="reset-container">
        <img src="images/reset.png" alt="reset-nav-bar" id="nav-bar-reset-icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toc-container" id="toc">
      <div class="content">
        <img id="lib-info" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Library Information</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="feat-ovw" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png" onclick="dropDown('feat-ovw')">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Feature Overview</a>
        <div class="l1-drop-container">
          <img class="l1-content-drop" id="feat-dtsht" src="images/plussearch.png" onclick="l1dropDown('feat-dtsht')">
          <a class="l1-content-link" href="feature_table_names.html" target="docWindow">Feature Datasheets</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="feat-chg" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Feature Changes</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="ran-fun" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">RAN Functions</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="cld-air" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">CloudAIR</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="net-inf" class="content-drop" src="images/plussearch.png">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Network Infrastructure</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works but it's performance is miserable in the original code, because the #topic-window element that you marked with the purple color includes an iFrame. I've tested to see if it works well without the iFrame inside that division and the answer is, yes. I hate to nag you about it but do you have any idea how I can figure a way around this?

Comment: All I've done is take your code, remove jquery-ui and replace with the add-in that was in the code you linked to.  You'd have to talk to the add-in maker for changes, or reverse-engineer it.